# how to assign values to the input elements using getElementByTagName?

Tags: javascript, html

In the below code, I am trying to assign some values to the input elements inside the cells by using getElementsByTagName, but i cannot achieve that by below logic, how to use getElementsByTagName to assign values to the input elements ?

```
      function buildTable(val)
      {
var myTable =document.getElementById("contentTable");
var j=val;
var r1=val;
var rows = [];
var cells = [];


while (myTable.hasChildNodes()) {
    myTable.removeChild(myTable.lastChild);
}


for( var i = 0; i < 1; i++ )
{
    rows[i] = myTable.insertRow(i);
    if(i%3==2)rows[i].addClass("every3rdrow");
    cells[i] = [];

    for( var x = 0; x < j ; x++ )
    {
        cells[i][x] =document.createElement((x==0)?"th":"td");
        cells[i][x].innerHTML = (x==0)?"<input id=t name=t[]  >":"<input id=t1 name=t1[] >";
        rows[rows.length - 1].appendChild(cells[i][x]);
        cells[i][x].getElementsByTagName("th")[0].innerHTML="3";
        cells[i][x].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML="2";
    }
}
 }
 buildTable();
```

Comment: you will not see anything in your example because j is null since nothing passed to buildTable(), try buildTable(6). Also I guess you are aware that addClass is jquery, not sure if you are using it and another thing you have condition for 3d row but your loop only does 1 loop. (i < 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cells[i][x].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value=3;
```